# In conda environment, "include cppyy" in python causes a seg fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, conda, cppyy

I am working in a anaconda environment use cppyy. For a few hours I have been getting segfaults when I import cppyy into python:

```
(CPPYY) > python
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:20:46) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cppyy
fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'zlib is not available'
Segmentation fault
```

"libzlib" and "zlib" are in my environment. Python segfaulting
is very rare.  What is happening?

2/3/22: The exact problem has happened again, and the suggested fix still works.  It happened after a "conda update --all".  If nothing is updated, there is no problem.
Here is the result of "conda list '(cppyy|zlib|python)'":

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cppyy                     2.2.0    py39ha3ed2ce_1    conda-forge
cppyy-backend             1.14.7   py39h1a9c180_0    conda-forge
cppyy-cling               6.25.2   py39h0f9e12e_1    conda-forge
cpycppyy                  1.12.8   py39h1a9c180_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.11   h36c2ea0_1013     conda-forge
python                    3.9.9    h62f1059_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2    pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-slugify            5.0.2             pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.9               2_cp39    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11     h36c2ea0_1013    conda-forge
```

Comment: Channel mixing perhaps? Please show `conda list '(cppyy|zlib|python)'` for the environment.

Comment: It would be helpful to report this to [the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/cppyy-cling-feedstock/issues).

Answer (score 1):

A priori, I've never seen this happen before, so I can't guess what lead up to this error (which says that the precompiled header of system files has been corrupted), but has zlib perhaps been updated after installing/running cppyy?

(To prevent mismatches, `cppyy-cling` actually has a builtin zlib; but I'm not sure whether the conda install is using that, though.)

If you delete the PCH, it will rebuild on first import of cppyy, which I expect to fix this problem. You can find it in your anaconda envs directory (use `conda info --envs` to locate). Do a search for `allDict.cxx.pch.*` there, then delete all such files found.

(The PCH is supposed to be replaced by precompiled modules, which have much better dependency management support in Clang itself. They work well on Linux and Mac, but I haven't been able to fully test on Windows yet, which is why cppyy still hasn't moved to them.)

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, [the `cppyy-cling` recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/cppyy-cling-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml) seems to [gut out the default build steps](https://github.com/conda-forge/cppyy-cling-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/use-dumb-setup.py.patch), and replace it with dynamically-linked libraries (kinda what makes Conda so efficient). However, it's still unclear to me whether the issue is that OP is improperly mixing channels (end-user error), e.g., zlib from defaults, or the recipe itself isn't being strict enough in constraining `zlib` dependency version (packaging issue).